# How to add dropdown.js dependency in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I followed the tutorial of split down button in bootstrap:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Try v1.2 Bootstrap Online</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
      data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
      data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here 2</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

While it didn't work in my application. As I inspect the element, the button-group didn't turn into btn-group open when I click the button. Can anyone help me with that? I have included the bootstrap in my application. I'm not sure what does the data-toggle = "dropdown" do. It seems that I have to include the dropdown.js in the file, but I've already included the bootstrap.min.js. Do I have to do something with the dependency?

Comment: Data-toggle is HTML5 data attribute that automatically hooks up the element to the type of widget it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not sure what the problem you are having.  I edited your code to the Bootstrap libraries from their CDN.  When I inspect the HTML, I see the "open" class being added to the button group.

Second Question - What is`data-toggle="dropdown"`, is used to tell dropdown.js plugin code this button is a dropdown.

Third Question - While it's not clear, all of the JavaScript plugins that are mentioned in Bootstrap documentation are already in the bootstrap.js file.

Comment: My question is that I cannot make the dropdown work. So the problem is that I'm not using the right bootstrap CDN. And now it works with the right bootstrap.js. I don't have to add dropdown.js dependency to the bootstrap.